# Change the submit function

Tags: 7, views

I am using VBO and I want to change the submit function on my form. I have tried the following code:

```
function a_views_bulk_operations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $vbo) {
  if($form_state['step']=='views_bulk_operations_confirm_form'){    
    $form['#submit'] = 'a_myfunc';
  }
}

function a_myfunc(&$form, &$form_state, $vbo) {
  dpm('Hit');
}
```

The `a_myfunc` is not hit. Instead I go to the normal VBO processing page. How can I change the submit function>

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding wrong submit handler, normally VBO submit handlers are available under $form['select'] key in $form array. You can confirm this in your case by printing $form in [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Make sure to use proper form ID as well before using, you can confirm form ID by printing $form_id variable available in hook_form_alter(). Below is example of altering VBO Form and overriding submit handler (In my case I've only one submit button).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function [MODULE_NAME]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Confirm $form_id before using.
  // echo "{$form_id}<br>";
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'VBO_FORM_ID':
      // In VBO, normally submit handlers are available under 'select' key.
      $form['select']['submit']['#submit'] = array('MODULE_NAME_vbo_submit');
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Submit handler for Views bulk operations.
 */
function MODULE_NAME_vbo_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do your processing here.
}
```